# Changing image color not working in dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, android-drawable

I am changing color of an image which is in drawable folder.

```
Drawable border = ContextCompat.getDrawable(homeActivity.this, R.drawable.buynow_button);
            ColorFilter borderFilter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.parseColor(Constants.buttonColor), Color.parseColor(Constants.buttonColor));
            border.setColorFilter(borderFilter);
```

I am using this image in 3 different activties and its working fine after changing color. But it doesn't change it's color when I use it in the dialog box

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
    android:tint="@color/red_tint"/>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I need to change color dynamically at run time

Comment: try this:

Drawable mDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.balloons); 
mDrawable.setColorFilter(new 
PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffff00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));

Comment: @ErumMalik did you try this solution?